Migrating data from One Drive to WebDav
We are trying to use a phython script to migrate data from one drive to webdav. we are getting bad request error
note - user@domain is replaced with the actual email address
DEBUG - https://graph.microsoft.com:443 "GET /v1.0/drives/01MPBGZN56Y2GOVW7725BZO354PWSELRRZ/root/children HTTP/1.1" 400 None

ERROR - Error migrating data for user user@domain: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/01MPBGZN56Y2GOVW7725BZO354PWSELRRZ/root/children
INFO - Starting migration for user: user@domain
DEBUG - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): graph.microsoft.com:443
DEBUG - https://graph.microsoft.com:443 "GET /v1.0/users/user@domain/drive/root HTTP/1.1" 200 None
INFO - Retrieved OneDrive root ID for user: user@domain
2024-12-03 11:17:00,522 - DEBUG - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): graph.microsoft.com:443
2024-12-03 11:17:00,674 - DEBUG - https://graph.microsoft.com:443 "GET /v1.0/drives/01SJLRXG56Y2GOVW7725BZO354PWSELRRZ/root/children HTTP/1.1" 400 None
2024-12-03 11:17:00,676 - ERROR - Error migrating data for user user@domain: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/01SJLRXG56Y2GOVW7725BZO354PWSELRRZ/root/children
2024-12-03 11:17:00,676 - INFO - Migration process completed for all users.

following is the script
